# Return single record which joining parents with multiple children

Tags: mysql

I am trying to join two tables (parent and child), but I only want one child returned for each parent...

```
select parent.name,child.name from parent left join child on parent.id=child.parentid
```

For the above, each child is returned and the parent is duplicated. I am not bothered which child is returned.

Thanks for any help

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is only a sample for @Mahesh Madushanka  .i will delete it later, but i cant format it in comment

**here my 2 tables**

```
MariaDB [yourSchema]> select id from table1;
+--------+
| id     |
+--------+
| 000001 |
| 000002 |
| 000003 |
| 000004 |
| 000005 |
| 000005 |
+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [yourSchema]> select id from table2;
+--------+
| id     |
+--------+
| 000001 |
| 000001 |
| 000002 |
| 000002 |
| 000003 |
| 000004 |
+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**result only with joins**

```
MariaDB [yourSchema]> SELECT t1.id,t2.id FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;
+--------+--------+
| id     | id     |
+--------+--------+
| 000001 | 000001 |
| 000001 | 000001 |
| 000002 | 000002 |
| 000002 | 000002 |
| 000003 | 000003 |
| 000004 | 000004 |
| 000005 |   NULL |
| 000005 |   NULL |
+--------+--------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**result with join and grouped - t1.id = 1 and 2 missed 1 time**

```
MariaDB [yourSchema]> SELECT t1.id,t2.id FROM table1 t1
    -> LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
    -> GROUP BY t2.id;
+--------+--------+
| id     | id     |
+--------+--------+
| 000005 |   NULL |
| 000001 | 000001 |
| 000002 | 000002 |
| 000003 | 000003 |
| 000004 | 000004 |
+--------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Not gonna lie, the choice of table names is fairly poor. Suggest defining what's considered a parent/child and foreign keys for joining.

Comment: That's great. Thanks for your time. Group By will do it alright. For some reason I always thought Left Join would just show you left with related right and right join would do the opposite...

Answer (score 0):

select parent.name,child.name from parent left join child on parent.id=child.parentid group by parent.id

Comment: `parent.id` *should* be unique... otherwise, the data model is pretty broken. That said, @mahesh's solution should be `group by parent.id`, since `parent.name` is probably *not* unique (as alluded to by @bernd).

Comment: @bernd he say "I only want one child returned for each parent"  if parent id is not unique that means we can have duplicate parent entries in parent table. but still according to his requirements he wants only one record for parent so this will work

Comment: This will only work if strict is turned off in MySQL.  It won't work with other databases.